# How to use parted or sfdisk to non-interactively partition a disk so that the partitions are properly aligned?

Tags: partition, parted

I'm trying to figure out how to partition a disk in a programmatic way so that my disk will have three "msdos" primary partitions: one for /boot, one for swap and the last for logical volumes. 
I can't use puppet or ansible or suchlike because of our customer's policies.

All the systems are configured with a single, 1TB disk.

- sda1 = /boot should be 512MB
- sda2 = swap  should be 16GB
- sda4 = the rest of the disk, extended partition for logical volumes.

I'd like to have these partitions aligned properly and I keep getting errors regarding the last partition not starting on a physical sector boundary.

Which type of unit should I use with parted? Would sfdisk be easier? I see posts where folks are using mebibytes **and** sectors in the same mkpart command and wonder why.

Comment: I've updated the title to remove the opinion-inducing aspect and focused it instead on the actual question you seem to have.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what's wrong with having an opinion about disk partitioning tools.
In any case I went with parted, since parted is what we've been using at work.
Just a reminder, this is for a physical disk. I wanted swap and boot on a physical partition and the remainder of the disk in one big partition for the logical volumes.

```
parted -s /dev/sda mklabel msdos
boot slice: 'parted -a optimal -s /dev/sda mkpart primary xfs 2048s 800MB'
swap slice: 'parted -s -a cylinder -- /dev/sda mkpart primary xfs 800MiB' 7720MiB
rest of disk: 'parted -s -a cylinder -- /dev/sda mkpart primary xfs 19087MiB -0'<br>
'pvcreate /dev/sda3' create physical volume
'vgcreate star /dev/sda3 create volume group
'lvcreate --size 10G --name tmp star' create temp volume
'lvcreate --size 30G --name home star' create home volume
'lvcreate --size 20G --name var star' create var volume
'lvcreate --size 20G --name var_log star' create /var/log volume
'lvcreate --size 20G --name var_audit star' create /var/log/audit volume
'lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n home star' create home volume with remaining space.
```